# How to lock a cell with formula in excel after the referred cell is filled?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using "CONCATENATE" formula in excel and I would like to lock (or turn the formula into value in) the cell which contains the formula after the last referred cell is filled. Some of the referred cells contain serial/sequence number.

So if someone would insert an extra line above, wouldn't screw the "Concatenated" cell.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use absolute references, which is achieved using the $ before the column and/or row

```
$A$1  'forces a reference of A and 1
$A1   'forces a reference only to A
A$1   'forces the reference to row 1
```

EG

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, " ", $B$3)
```

Comment: From what I can discern from the question, this is the correct answer.